# mocking method inside another method scala

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalamock

I am having a problem while mocking a method that is being called in another method.

For example: Below in my main class.

```
class Trial extends TrialTrait {

  def run(): String ={
    val a = createA()
    val b = a.split(" ")
    val c = b.size
    val d = c + " words are there"
    d
  }

  def createA(): String = {
    var a = "above all the things that have been done, one thing remained in silent above all the things that have been done one thing remained in silent above all the that "
    a
  }
}
```

Below is my mock code.

```
class TryMock4 extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterEach with MockFactory {

  val trial = new Trial
  val st = stub[TrialTrait]

  test("Mocking the DataFrame") {
    val input = "above all the things that have been done, one thing remained in silent above "
    (st.createA  _).when().returns(input)
    val expected = "14 words are there"
    val actual = st.run()
    Assert.assertEquals(expected,actual)
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is, passing mocking data to `createA` and use that in the `run` method.

But, it is giving `null` value after running the `run` method.

Could you please suggest how it can be achieved?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with ScalaMock. But you can do it with [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) using [`spy`](http://javadoc.io/page/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy-T-). But actually that fact that you need to mock an inner method to test is a sign of some wrong design. So I strongly suggest first consider refactoring your code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @SergGr. Can you please let me know how we can do it with Mockito using spy.I would appreciate if you can provide a sample code..

Comment: Aswanikumar have you read the documentation I linked (the second link)? Have you tried that? Where exactly is your problem with `spy`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a mock in this case, just a regular override should suffice.

```
class TrialTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  behavior of "Trial"

  it should "count words" in {
    val input = "above all the things that have been done, one thing remained in silent above "

    val trial = new Trial {
      override def createA(): String = input
    }

    val expected = "14 words are there"
    val actual = trial.run()
    actual should be (expected)
  }
}
```

However, should you really want to use a mock here, it's possible with scalamock.
You can define our own class that makes part of the class final (the bit you don't want to mock), see below:

```
class TrialTestWithMock extends FlatSpec with Matchers with MockFactory {
  behavior of "Trial"

  it should "count words" in {
    val input = "above all the things that have been done, one thing remained in silent above "

    class FinalTrial extends Trial {
      final override def run(): String = super.run()
    }

    val trial = mock[FinalTrial]

    (trial.createA _).expects().returning(input).anyNumberOfTimes()
    val expected = "14 words are there"
    val actual = trial.run()
    actual should be (expected)
  }
}
```